# Confusion about a certain limit

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification

In between of an exercise of a book, i was trying to prove the product rule of differentiation.

I got this limit while proving:

$=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [ g(x+\Delta x)\cdot\dfrac {f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x} + f(x)\cdot\dfrac {g(x+\Delta x)-g(x)}{\Delta x} ]  $

$=g(x)\cdot \dfrac{df}{dx} + f(x)\cdot \dfrac{dg}{dx}$

Was it okay to say that $g(x+\Delta x)\to g(x)$ as $\Delta x\to 0$ in the first term?

Comment: Note that you need $f$ and $g$ both to be differentiable for the product rule to be true. And all differentiable functions are continuous.

Comment: @JohnBrevik yes that is true for both $f$ and $g$.

Comment: OK, so given that $g$ is continuous, what is $\displaystyle{\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} g(x+\Delta x)}$?

Comment: @JohnBrevik It should be $g(x)$?

Comment: Yes. Do you see why, though?

Comment: $g(x + 0) = g(x)$ right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Was it okay to say that $g(x+\Delta x)\to g(x)$ as $\Delta x\to 0$ in the first term?

Recall when we can split a limit into two limits.

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(P(x)Q(x)\right)=\lim_{x\to0}P(x)\cdot \lim_{x\to0}Q(x)$$

Only if $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ for $x\to0$ are finite. In your case, both $g(x+\Delta x)$ and $\dfrac {f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$ are finite for $\Delta x\to0$.

Comment: This means its correct right? Also, how would I be able to know if they are not finite?

Comment: They are finite because in order to have a derivative, a function must be continuous.

Comment: It's the limits which must be finite, not the value at the limit point.

Comment: @aschepler. correct.

Comment: So if incase $\Delta x\to \infty$ this would be an infinite limit right?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui. It really depends on the functions in which $\Delta x$ appears. BTW, it is `\infty` not `\infinity`.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Oh yes, got it! Thanks alot.